# InProc distributed cache in .Net 4.0

Tags: caching, .net-4.0, appfabric

How does InProc distributed cache in .Net 4.0 deal with serialisation?

Is there any plugins or  thirdparty frameworks that support it out of the box?

Comment: Seems like "in process" (InProc) and "distributed" are mutually exclusive... You can't be distributed (across machines, or even processes) if you're running in-process...

Comment: Maybe what he means is use AppFabric (or some other cache framework) running in the same machine as the application which is definitely not inProc.

Comment: If you could please explain a little bit further what your concerns are maybe we can help

Answer (score 1):

Windows Server AppFabric cache supports serialization of any CLR object out of the box.

And you can have an InProc cache that is synchronized with distributed cache, so he is not necessarily wrong.